# "Request contains invalid agrument" when updating a log sink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm attempting to update an existing sink using the (Python) Google Stackdriver Logging API, and am getting an error that I can't track down.

The API explorer for the method in question is [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/logging/v2/logging.projects.sinks.update), to which I'm supplying `projects/my_project/sinks/my_sink_name` as the `sinkName`, and the following for the Request Body:

```
{
  "name": "audit_logs",
  "destination": "bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my_project/datasets/destination_dataset",
  "filter": "resource.type=\"bigquery_resource\""
}
```

When submitting, I get the following error:

```
400 Bad Request

{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

...which doesn't specify *which* argument is invalid, and I have tried several variations without any success.

Additional info: this request is based on one generated by the Python API. I have also tried specifying the full path of the sink in `name` to no avail, which is what the Python API generates, which seems contrary to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/billingAccounts.sinks#LogSink).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the UpdateSink with uniqueWriterIdentity set to true?

From https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.sinks/update:

"It is an error if the old value is true and the new value is set to false or defaulted to false."